# Fastest and robust way to replace various occurencies of a string in dom objects with JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, replace

I have written a function which replace all occurence of "@TransResource....." e.g. "@TransResource.Contact.Send" with the replacement from a json array.

example for occurence could be:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-block js-send">@TransResource.Contact.Send</button>

<input type="text" class="form-control" id="LastName" name="LastName" placeholder="@TransResource.Contact.LastName">

<a href="#">@TransResource.Contact.LastName"</a>
```

All went fine, except IE/edge lost some translations and I am unable to figure out why.
Can one solve this and/or has a better or robust approach?

You can see, the fiddle works perfect in Chrome, but the button text translation is missing in edge.

[here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mattopen/x27qmry3/)

my JavaScript code.

```
var
getLocalResource = function (key) {
    try {
        var retVal = key;
        retVal = StringResource[retVal] === null || StringResource[retVal] === undefined ? retVal : StringResource[retVal];
        return retVal;
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log(arguments.callee.name + ": " + err);
    }
},
translate = function (node) {
    try {
        var pattern = /@TransResource.[a-zA-Z0-9.]+/g;
        if (!node) node = $("body *");

        node.contents().each(function () {
            if (this.nodeType === 3) {
                this.nodeValue = this.nodeValue.replace(pattern, function (match, entity) {
                    return getLocalResource(match.slice(15));
                });
            }

            if (this.attributes) {
                for (var i = 0, atts = this.attributes, n = atts.length, arr = []; i < n; i++) {
                    if (atts[i].nodeValue !== "") { // Ignore this node it is an empty text node
                        atts[i].nodeValue = atts[i].nodeValue.trim().replace(pattern, function (match, entity) {
                            return getLocalResource(match.slice(15));
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    catch (err) {
        console.log(arguments.callee.name + ": " + err);
    }
};
```

and the json:

```
var StringResource = {
    "Contact.EmailAddress": "Email address",
    "Contact.Headline": "Contact",
    "Contact.Description": "please leaf us a message...?",
    "Contact.Teasertext": "Please leaf us a message <b>bold text</b>",
    "Contact.Telephone": "Telephone",
    "Contact.Send": "Send",
    "Page.Contact": "Contact"
};
```

**edit (this is now my solution):**
thanks to @Chris-G, his comment removes the IE issue and also thanks to @trincot for the perfomance update. All together is now this script:

```
var
getLocalResource = function (key) {
    try {
        var retVal = key;
        retVal = StringResource[retVal] === null || StringResource[retVal] === undefined ? retVal : StringResource[retVal];
        return retVal;
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log(arguments.callee.name + ": " + err);
    }
},
translate = function (node) {
    try {
        var pattern = /@TransResource.[a-zA-Z0-9.]+/g;
        if (!node) node = $("body *");

        node.contents().each(function () {
            if (this.nodeType === 3 && this.nodeValue.trim().length) {
                var s = this.nodeValue.replace(pattern, function (match, entity) {
                    return getLocalResource(match.slice(15));
                });
                if (this.nodeValue !== s) this.nodeValue = s;
            }

            if (this.attributes) {
                for (var i = 0, atts = this.attributes, n = atts.length, arr = []; i < n; i++) {
                    if (atts[i].nodeValue !== "") { // Ignore this node it is an empty text node
                        atts[i].nodeValue = atts[i].nodeValue.trim().replace(pattern, function (match, entity) {
                            return getLocalResource(match.slice(15));
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    catch (err) {
        console.log(arguments.callee.name + ": " + err);
    }
};
```

Comment: Not sure about fast and robust, but the fix is to use `if (this.nodeType === 3 && this.nodeValue.trim().length)` instead (otherwise your code is trying to call replace on tons of empty nodes, and IE borks at some point).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in IE is that for the `textarea` node, when it has no content, the assignment to `node.nodeValue` will trigger an exception "Invalid argument". Don't ask me why.

If you even add as little as a space in the HTML between the opening and closing `textarea` tag, the error disappears, but if you do that the placeholder attribute becomes useless.

But you could also work around the problem in the code, by only assigning to `node.nodeValue` when the assigned value is different from its current value:

```
if (this.nodeType === 3) {
    var s = this.nodeValue.replace(pattern, function (match, entity) {
        return getLocalResource(match.slice(15));
    });
    if (this.nodeValue !== s) this.nodeValue = s;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but I am with @ChrisG `s answer. It will remove the IE issue in an easy way.

Comment: That's fine. Just to note that this solution will give an additional gain, as it not only prevents assignment to empty values, but to all values that do not change. It is the assignment to `nodeValue` that represents the most work in this part of the code, so avoiding it (not only when `length` is zero) gives the most gain. As you were asking for "fastest", I am sure that if you would compare the performance, this one would score better.

Comment: ah ok, sounds good. I will do some test later. thanks for the hint